# Trying to print an url that is inside of a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, image, parsing, sdk

I'm trying to do this in parse. So i want to get the url in the image:

```
var Encharcamientos1 = Parse.Object.extend("Report");
var query = new Parse.Query(Inundaciones1);
query.equalTo("Tipo_Reporte", "Encharcamientos");
query.find({


success: function(results) {
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var object = results[i];
    if(object.get("ImageFile") !== '' && typeof object.get("ImageFile") !== 'undefined' || object.get("ImageFile") == true) {
        var file = object.get("ImageFile");
        console.log(file);
        var liga = file.url;
        document.getElementById(".imagen").innerHTML = liga;
    }
```

The console log throw me this, the url I need, so How can i print that url in order to show the image? (for example ):

```
b.File {_name: "tfss-b59f1559-1ac4-4b49-8191-f167a95b7e69-Ruben-Espinosa-1.jpg", _url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/9ab97f5c-e03d-4602-a7be…-1ac4-4b49-8191-f167a95b7e69-Ruben-Espinosa-1.jpg"}
```

Thanks

Comment: I put the variable liga on the code. I forgot to put it, but it doesn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acces the _url field use:

`var liga = file["_url"];`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code

```
    // ENCHARCAMIENTOS
    var Encharcamientos1 = Parse.Object.extend("Report");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Inundaciones1);
    query.equalTo("Tipo_Reporte", "Encharcamientos");
    query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var object = results[i];
    if(object.get("ImageFile") !== '' && typeof object.get("ImageFile") !== 'undefined' || object.get("ImageFile") == true) {
        var file = object.get("ImageFile");
        var liga = file["_url"];
    }
     L.marker([object.get('Latitud'),object.get('Longitud') ], {icon: EncharcamientosIcon}).bindPopup(' <p><span class="grande"> ' + object.get('Tipo_Reporte') + ' </span></p><p>Fecha: ' + object.get('Fecha') + ' </p><p>Hora: ' + object.get('Hora') + '<div class="imagen"><img src="' + liga + '"></div>' + '</p><p>Comentarios:<br /> ' + noundefined(object.get('Comentario')) + '</p>').addTo(Encharcamientos).addTo(todos);
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
var liga = file["_url"];
```

Or

```
var liga = file._url;
```